# Spark custom streaming datasource?

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

i am trying to figure out what is the current recomanded way to create a custom streaming data source with spark structured streaming latest version.

I found the following tutorial https://aamargajbhiye.medium.com/apache-spark-custom-streaming-data-source-6c3c7ffbd3d4

but the interfaces are outdated and do not exist anymore. Hence i was wondering what does exist today ? It would for readying in files.